# is there any way to set context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop to false when using serverless-http and netlify-lambda

Tags: serverless, netlify, netlify-function

I am using serverless-http and netlify-lambda to use express to make serverless functions. Is there any way to asceses the context variable normally accusable when making a serverless function with netlify?